# Elasticsearch - TikaOnDotNet Text Extraction page by page

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-tika, text-extraction

We are exploring the elastic search and currently we are extracting the text from ms office documents, pdf, .eml and other file formats using [TikaOnDotNet](https://kevm.github.io/tikaondotnet/).

We want to store the document content page by page to Elasticsearch. so that we can update users that the keyword you were looking for is available on page number x.

I am not sure whether it is possible or not, if you could share you though on the same or show some direction would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Hiten

Comment: Fetch the text from Tika as XHTML rather than plain text, split on the page divs for the formats which support that, then save the text of each page div?

Comment: Thank you for the direction, we will check the XHTML and will get back you. Just to have quick question, we may get multiple divs, so based on what we can judge that page break starts from particular div.

Comment: You'll be looking for `<div class="page">` in the output

Comment: @Gagravarr - yes i got the same, thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Here are my findings based on your input, .pdf - page (class) .xlsx - div .xls - div, .ppt - slide-content (class) .pptx - slide-content (class) .rtf (rich text format) but for .doc, .docx, .eml .dgw .txt no class found. Any suggestions plz

Comment: Most of those formats don't store page information in the files, so that's largely as expected

Comment: How about .doc and .docx, it store the information for of page break and new paragraph etc. Can you suggest how to differentiate between both?

Comment: The Microsoft Word formats don't include page information, other than page breaks and section breaks. You would need to use Word or OpenOffice or similar to render them to a PDF then parse the PDF if you need to know what text goes on what page

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes, that can be done, but again, thousands of documents need to be converted to pdf and the content extracted again. Any alternative suggestion are highly appreciated.

Comment: Pick a different file format to start with?